# バックボタンを押してアプリを終了してもバックグラウンドで継続してしまう

Tags: android, monaca, cordova

monacaでcordova4.1になりましたがこれにすると
Andoroidでバックボタンで抜けるとバックグラウンドでアプリが動いた状態になっている様です
BGMやゲームが進行して定期的になる効果音などが鳴ります
デバッガでもビルドしてもなります
※アプリ履歴を消すととまります

以前はそんなことありませんでしたし
cordovaを3.5に落してビルドするとなりません

私がenchant.jsで作っているからでしょうか？
ためしにバックボタンを押したらゲームが終了するようにしてみましたが
改善しませんでした、、
もちろん私のバックボタンイベントがちゃんとかけていないのかもしれませんが、、

対処方法ご存知の方いらっしゃればご教示ください

Answer (score 2):

下記の様にdocument.addEventListener で pause と resume のイベントに音楽の停止と再生を記述してみてください。

```
document.addEventListener("pause", function() { bgm.pause(); },false);
document.addEventListener("resume", function() { bgm.play(); },false);
```